# Конвертирование странного числа в формат rgb

Tags: javascript, hex, rgb

Пытаюсь получить цвет в формате rgb от моей wifi лампочки, но получаю это:

```
"2442110"
```

Как я могу это расшифровать?

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: вот так этот вопрос выглядит: "я что-то делаю, у меня что-то получается. Как из этого получить то, что мне нужно?" Ну как, смог бы ответить на такой вопрос?

Comment: Читайте документацию к лампочке, наверное?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3):

По всей видимости, ваша лампочка возвращает значение цвета в формате Decimal.

Я нашел на просторах enSO [функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55787954/12303413), позволяющую конвертировать этот формат в rgba:

```js
function ARGBtoRGBA(num) {
  num >>>= 0;
  let b = num & 0xFF,
    g = (num & 0xFF00) >>> 8,
    r = (num & 0xFF0000) >>> 16,
    a = ((num & 0xFF000000) >>> 24) / 255;
  return "rgba(" + [r, g, b, a].join(",") + ")";
}

let x = ARGBtoRGBA(2442110);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Она что синим светит?

Comment: @Arcadiy, главное чтоб не прозрачным... на кой лампочке было палитру с альфа каналом делать - тайна века...))))

Answer (score 2):

Каждый цвет в `RGB` - это числа, которые принимают значения `[0, 255] -> [0, 16^2 - 1]`

Чтобы перевести из `RGB` - в число нужно умножать каждую из них на 256 в степени позиции, но позиционировать надо с права налево

Например: пусть есть `R(1)G(1)B(1)` - делаем следующее:

`256^0 * B(1) + 256^1 * G(1) + 256^2 * R(1) = 1 * 1 + 256 * 1 + 65536 * 1 = 65793`

У нас же задача ровно обратная из числа получить цвета `RGB`

Пусть нам дано число `65793`, тогда надо:

1. Разделить это число на `256^2 = 65536` => `65793 / 65536 = 1 (257)`
2. Делим остаток на `256^1 = 256` => `257 / 256 = 1 (1)`
3. Делим остаток на `256^0 = 1` => `1 / 1 = 1`

Таким образом можно любое число представить в виде `RGB`

Код:

```js
const intToRGB = (int) => {
  const R = Math.floor(int / 256 ** 2);
  const G = Math.floor((int % 256 ** 2) / 256 ** 1);
  const B = ((int % 256 ** 2) % 256) / 256 ** 0;
  
  return `R - ${R} G - ${G} B - ${B}`;
}

const integers = [0, 65793, 2442110, 16777215];

console.log(integers.map(intToRGB));
```

Или же

```js
const intToRGB = (int) => {
  const R = Math.floor(int / 65536);
  const G = Math.floor((int % 65536) / 256);
  const B = (int % 65536) % 256;
  
  return `R - ${R} G - ${G} B - ${B}`;
}

const integers = [0, 65793, 2442110, 16777215];

console.log(integers.map(intToRGB));
```

Или же

```js
const intToRGB = (int) => {  
  const R = Math.floor(int / 65536);
  
  int -= R * 65536;
  
  const G = Math.floor(int / 256);
  const B = int - G * 256;
  
  return `R - ${R} G - ${G} B - ${B}`;
}

const integers = [0, 65793, 2442110, 16777215];

console.log(integers.map(intToRGB));
```

Или же

```js
const intToRGB = (int) => {  
  const R = int >> 16;
  
  int -= R << 16;
  
  const G = int >> 8;  
  const B = int - (G << 8);
  
  return `R - ${R} G - ${G} B - ${B}`;
}

const integers = [0, 65793, 2442110, 16777215];

console.log(integers.map(intToRGB));
```

Однострочник (не используйте это :) )

```js
const intToRGB = (int) => `R - ${int >> 16} G - ${int -= (int >> 16) << 16, int >> 8} B - ${int - ((int >> 8) << 8)}`;

const integers = [0, 65793, 2442110, 16777215];

console.log(integers.map(intToRGB));
```